# Hide Youtube subscription button on website if someone is subscribed

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm using the code of google to add a youtube subscription button to my wordpress website:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default">
```

When I use the inspector of the browser I see a different classes:

- When I'm subscribed: yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded
- When I'm not   subcribed: yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded

My idea was to hide the button with javascript via CSS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded).style.visibility='hidden';
```

This didn't work.

Via the console I tried to debug the problem:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded"));
```

and the console showed no class. But I see the class via the inspector.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's in an iframe, you can't do it

Comment: You might be able to do this with the [Youtube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: This is not possible with the iFrame API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using only css and set the class relative to not subscribed to: *display: none;*

```css
.yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded"> Subscribed </h1>
<h1 class="yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded"> Not Subscribed </h1>
```

---

### Second Try

In JavaScript you can use .querySelector(".yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded") so when it exists it replaces the innerHTML of the parent with the html tags you want.

```js
const ytSubBtn = document.querySelector(".yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded");
const ytContainer = document.querySelector(".yt-sub");

if (ytSubBtn.classList.contains('yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded')) {
    ytContainer.innerHTML = "<h2 style='color: tomato;'> This is added via JS and replaces the Subscribe button</h2>"
}
```

```css
*{
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.yt-subscribed {
  display: none;
}

.yt-sub{
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Option 1: they are subscribed so the JavaScript gets the element by the class name and replaces the interior of yt-sub with the code you want to add.-->

<div class="yt-sub">
  <h2 class="yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded"> You're already subscribed </h2>
</div>

<!-- Option 2: they are not subscribed, so the h2 has a different class that the one we are looking in the JS, it stays the same.-->

<div class="yt-sub">
  <h2 class="yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded"> Not Subscribed </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I also was thinking. But I also want to show some text if someone is subscribed. Hidding the button with css is not an option, I think.

Comment: Okay so then you'd need some JavaScript to it, let me try it

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. When I try this: <script type="text/javascript">
const ytSubBtn = document.querySelector(".yt-uix-button-subscribed-branded");
console.log(ytSubBtn);
</script>. It returns a NULL. I tried this when I was subcribed and unsubcribed.